# Restrain user interaction within a specific cell range in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, spreadsheet-protection

I would like to limit the range in which the user can navigate though the cells. To explain better, suppose that range is within the rows 1 to 10 and columns A to G. The user cannot select any cell outside that limit or explore cells outside that boundary.

Is there any way to accomplish this using VBA or Excel functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock all the cells in the sheet (that is the default), unlock A1:G10 (HOME > Cells - Format, Protection, uncheck Locked) and Protect Sheet... with only *Select unlocked cells* checked.

If you then select A1 and keep pressing enter you will see the selection is restricted to the range you chose.